# single word request - What do you call someone that uses something in a wrong way?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my sentence, I wrote:

> There are some categories of users who use smartphones in the wrong way.

But I think, the phrase "users who use smartphone in the wrong way" can be simplified into a single word or two. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You will need to rewrite the whole sentence. It is worded very clumsily, and the sentiment expressed comes across as arrogant if not outright wrong.

Comment: If you want a word for such a person, one might call them an ***abuser*** but you have to be very careful as that term has a lot of negative connotations so if you're unaware of them, I wouldn't recommend using the word _abuser_.

Comment: They've being *creative*.

Comment: Are they like, using it as a hammer? How do you use a smartphone wrongly? If they film vertically, use a derogative term of your choice. Or try ***inept***.

Answer (score 1):

**misuse**, as defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misuse):

> **Use (something) in the wrong way or for the wrong purpose.**
>   *he was found guilty of misusing public funds*

Therefore, your sentence could be reworded into:

> users who **misuse** smartphones

Comment: There is also [mistreat](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mistreat) if the person is operating the device correctly but not taking very good care of it.  (*cough*my son*cough*)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly how much you require the sentence to be shortened (there is nothing wrong with *misuse*), you could also rephrase it as:

> . . . who use smartphones **incorrectly**.